# I can't configure CakePHP 2.1.0 with MongoDB Datasource Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, mongodb

I have gotten the latest CakePHP (2.1.0) and MongoDB Datasource Plugin both from git, and have followed the configuration settings as best as I can.  I have placed the MonogoDB plugin in the plugins directory, and updated both my database.php and bootstrap.php files:

bootstrap.php:

```
CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');
```

database.php:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

  public $default = array(
  'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
      'database' => 'database',
      'host' => 'staff.mongohq.com',
      'port' => 10070,
      'login' => 'user', 
      'password' => 'secret'
  );
```

}

I'm afraid I'm missing something stupid, but I keep getting the error:

> **Datasource class MongodbSource could not be found.**

Which to me, implies it can find the plugin, but not the datasource class.  Anyone seen this before?  I've also tried to connect to a locally installed MongoDB, but same error persists.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to pull the plugin so it pulls the cake2.0 branch instead (which uses the correct cake 2.x directory naming conventions):

```
git clone -b cake2.0 git://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb.git Mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using the CakePHP-Mongo plugin for CakePHP 2.0 and not CakePHP 1.3